# How to format polars.Duration?

Tags: python, python-polars

This:

```
df = (polars
  .DataFrame(dict(
    j=['2023-01-02 03:04:05.111', '2023-01-08 05:04:03.789'],
    k=['2023-01-02 03:04:05.222', '2023-01-02 03:04:05.456'],
    ))
  .select(
    polars.col('j').str.to_datetime(),
    polars.col('k').str.to_datetime(),
    )
  .with_columns(
    l=polars.col('k') - polars.col('j'),
    )
  )
print(df)
```

produces:

```
 j (datetime[μs])         k (datetime[μs])         l (duration[μs])
 2023-01-02 03:04:05.111  2023-01-02 03:04:05.222  111ms
 2023-01-08 05:04:03.789  2023-01-02 03:04:05.456  -6d -1h -59m -58s -333ms
shape: (2, 3)
```

Doing this afterwards:

```
print(df
  .select(
    polars.col('l').dt.to_string('%s.%f')
    )
  )
```

raises:

```
polars.exceptions.InvalidOperationError: `to_string` operation not supported for dtype `duration[μs]`
```

How would I go about formatting this to a string with a custom format like I can do with `polars.Datetime`?

Comment: What about `.dt.seconds()`

Comment: @DeanMacGregor that just gives me the seconds (so e.g. for 1.123s i'll get 1, without 123ms) and it also doesn't allow me to format (e.g. to say "1s123ms" or something along the lines), right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to use `pl.format` and cobble together what you want with `dt.seconds`, `dt.milliseconds`, etc. These aren't intended to be used together so if you do it'll be (roughly) doubling (for 2 elements) the total time so, imo, best to use the most granular unit and do the math yourself since you've got to some some math anyways.

This should work for the `"%Ss%fms"` case

```
df.with_columns(
    z=pl.format("{}s{}ms", 
                ((milli:=pl.col('l').dt.milliseconds()).abs().floordiv(1000))*milli.sign(), 
                milli.abs().mod(1000))
)
shape: (2, 4)
┌─────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ j                       ┆ k                       ┆ l                        ┆ z             │
│ ---                     ┆ ---                     ┆ ---                      ┆ ---           │
│ datetime[μs]            ┆ datetime[μs]            ┆ duration[μs]             ┆ str           │
╞═════════════════════════╪═════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ 2023-01-02 03:04:05.111 ┆ 2023-01-02 03:04:05.222 ┆ 111ms                    ┆ 0s111ms       │
│ 2023-01-08 05:04:03.789 ┆ 2023-01-02 03:04:05.456 ┆ -6d -1h -59m -58s -333ms ┆ -525598s333ms │
└─────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────┴───────────────┘
```